# Can't Find Last Remaining Chest!

Tags: the-spongebob-squarepants-movie

In the level "Shell City, Dead Ahead" from Spongebob Squarepants Movie Game, I can't find one chest, I think it's the hardest chest from this game. What I have to do to unlock this chest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing, is, change your character to **Spongebob**. After this, play the **Guitar Challenge**. You'll see some **toasters** with visible **toast**, and you'll have to **hit them** with the power of your **guitar**. There are **3 toasts** that you must hit to unlock this chest. In this video, you can see better how to get this chest:

.

Comment: I already suspected these toasters ...